# listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord (String name, UUID uuid) Not working

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

So im trying to get this little piece of code to run

```
public AcceptThread() {
    // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmServerSocket,
    // because mmServerSocket is final
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
    try {
        // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the client code
        tmp = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("Server", MY_UUID);
    } catch (IOException e) { }
    mmServerSocket = tmp;
}
```

But when i continue from the line where tmp should be assigned it is still null. Bluetooth is activated and everything but it simply wont set tmp to anything when i get to it. Any ideas why not? And btw. does this method not work on a 2.2 android machine since it crashes at that line on my 2.2 machine but not on my 4.1.2 device.

If any more information is needed to be able to answer please just ask for it and ill give it to the best of my ability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out i hadn't given permission to the app to use bluetooth so solved.

Answer (score 1):

I am completely new to Android development and ran into the same problem. Here is more help if other people run into this:

Because this is happening on the server side, be sure discoverability is enabled before starting the accept-connection thread. This can by starting the thread in the onActivityResult() method when the proper resultCode is received.